# Map only jobs in spark (vs hadoop streaming)

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-streaming

I have a function `process_line` that maps from the input format to the output format

Some rows are corrupted, and need to be ignored.

I am successfully running this code as a python streaming job:

```
for input_line in sys.stdin:
    try:
        output_line=process_line(input_line.strip())
        print (output_line)
    except:
        sys.stderr.write('Error with line: {l}\n'.format(l=input_line))
        continue
```

How can I run the equivalent code in pyspark ?
This is what I tried:

```
input = sc.textFile(input_dir, 1)
output=lines.map(process_line)
output.saveAsTextFile(output_dir)
```

How can I keep track of corrupted lines and have statistics on their count ?

Comment: What is the problem with your pyspark code? Did you get any errors? Can you elaborate some more?

Comment: It seems to be taking longer than the hadoop streaming for some reason, and how do I account for the corrupted lines ?

Comment: I see that you read the textfile to only 1 partition. This may cause the slowness. Try to remove it and let spark decide the number of partitions on its own and then check it.

Comment: See: [What is the equivalent to scala.util.Try in pyspark?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33383275/1560062) and [Spark Programming Guide - Accumulators](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#accumulators-a-nameaccumlinka)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to read the text file to only one partition, which can cause your job to run slowly because you basically give up the parallelism.

Try to do this:

```
input = sc.textFile(input_dir)
output = lines.map(process_line)
output.saveAsTextFile(output_dir)
```

As for the corrupted lines, you can use a try-except mechanism in your `process_line` function and maybe write to some log file the problematic line, or try to do some other logic instead.