# Remove elements from Spark RDD

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am building an RDD from a text file. Some of the lines do not conform to the format I am expecting, in which case I use the marker -1.

```
def myParser(line):
    try:
        # do something
    except:
        return (-1, -1), -1

lines = sc.textFile('path_to_file')
pairs = lines.map(myParser)
```

is it possible to remove the lines with the `-1` marker? If not, what would be the workaround for it?

Comment: just use `filter` ... no?

Comment: In Java I use a filter : .filter(new Function<CassandraRow, Boolean>() { public Boolean call(CassandraRow row) throws Exception {return row.getString("value").equals(whatIWant);
                    }
                }).

Comment: what would be the argument of the lambda function. key, value or both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cleanest solution I can think of is to discard malformed lines using a `flatMap`:

```
def myParser(line):
    try:
        # do something
        return [result] # where result is the value you want to return
    except:
        return []

sc.textFile('path_to_file').flatMap(myParser)
```

See also [What is the equivalent to scala.util.Try in pyspark?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33383275/1560062)

You can also filter after the `map`:

```
pairs = lines.map(myParser).filter(lambda x: x != ((-1, -1), -1))
```