# How can I return an empty (null?) item back from a map method in PySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I am writing a map method using

```
RDD.map(lambda line: my_method(line))
```

and based on a particular condition in my_method (let's say line starts with 'a'), I want to either return a particular value otherwise ignore this item all together.

For now, I am returning -1 if the condition is not met on the item and later using another

```
RDD.filter() method to remove all the ones with -1.
```

Any better way to be able to ignore these items by returning null from my_method?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In case like this `flatMap` is your friend:

1. Adjust `my_method` so it returns either a single element list or an empty list (or create a wrapper like here [What is the equivalent to scala.util.Try in pyspark?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33383275/1560062))

   ```
   def my_method(line):
       return [line.lower()] if line.startswith("a") else []
   ```
2. `flatMap`

   ```
   rdd = sc.parallelize(["aDSd", "CDd", "aCVED"])

   rdd.flatMap(lambda line: my_method(line)).collect()
   ## ['adsd', 'acved']
   ```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to ignore the items based on some condition, then why not use `filter` by itself?  Why use a map?  If you want to transform it, you can use map on the output from filter.

Answer (score -1):

`filter` is transformation method. It is high-cost operation because of creating new RDD.