# Pyspark - saveAsTable throws index error while show() dataframe works perfectly

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Trying to save dataframe as table.

I am able to create dataframe and create temp table as well. But saving the same dataframe using saveAsTable() throws index error.

I checked the schema of Dataframe, this seems to be ok.

Not sure what is the issue and  couldn't get anything from the log other than index error.

>

```
>>> sqlContext.sql('select * from bx_users limit 2').show()
+-------+--------------------+----+
|User-ID|            Location| Age|
+-------+--------------------+----+
|      1|  nyc, new york, usa|NULL|
|      2|stockton, califor...|  18|
+-------+--------------------+----+

>>> bx_users_df.show(2)
+-------+--------------------+----+
|User-ID|            Location| Age|
+-------+--------------------+----+
|      1|  nyc, new york, usa|NULL|
|      2|stockton, califor...|  18|
+-------+--------------------+----+
only showing top 2 rows

>>> bx_users_df.printSchema()
root
 |-- User-ID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Location: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Age: string (nullable = true)

>>> bx_users_df.write.format('parquet').mode('overwrite').saveAsTable('bx_user')
18/05/19 00:12:36 ERROR util.Utils: Aborting task
org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 111, in main
    process()
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 106, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 263, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
IndexError: list index out of range

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.next(PythonRDD.scala:129)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.next(PythonRDD.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.next(InterruptibleIterator.scala:43)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer$$anonfun$writeRows$1.apply$mcV$sp(WriterContainer.scala:261)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer$$anonfun$writeRows$1.apply(WriterContainer.scala:260)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer$$anonfun$writeRows$1.apply(WriterContainer.scala:260)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1279)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer.writeRows(WriterContainer.scala:266)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:148)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:148)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:242)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
18/05/19 00:12:37 ERROR datasources.DefaultWriterContainer: Task attempt attempt_201805190012_0222_m_000000_0 aborted.
18/05/19 00:12:37 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 222.0 (TID 245)
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer.writeRows(WriterContainer.scala:269)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:148)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:148)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:242)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: you must be looking for `bx_users_df.write.format('parquet').mode('overwrite').parquet('bx_user')`

Comment: Can you try to specify the path to your data warehouse ? i.e `bx_users_df.write.format('parquet').option('path','path/to/dw').mode('overwrite').saveAsTable('bx_user')`

Comment: Eliasah - I tried that, but not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the biggest Spark gotchas is that operation are lazy, and even if call an action, Spark will try to do as little work as possible.

`show` for example will try to evaluate only 20 first rows - if there are no wide transformations in the pipeline it won't process all data. This is why `show` can work, while `saveAsTable` fails.

You code fails in lambda expression:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
```

as a result:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

This is almost always user mistake in lack of handling of malformed data. I suspect your code contains something similar to

```
(sc.textFile(...)
    .map(lambda line: line.split(...)
    .map(lambda xs: (xs[0], xs[1], xs[3])))
```

and your code fails when line doesn't contain expected number of arguments.

In general prefer standard functions which handle possible exceptions, or use [other methods](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33383275/9613318) to avoid failures.

And if it is just parsing delimited data file (CSV, TSV) use [Spark CSV reader](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28782940/9613318).

Comment: Thanks a lot, i am using databricks and with the cell based notebook structure its easy to forget that lazy evaluation is happening in some prior cell. Helped me solve a problem, I easily wasted 1 hour!